# Can I delete and add new video with same title in YouTube?

Tags: youtube, video

I have just added a video which is very low quality but I have high quality video with me. We can use annotation but I don't want to make as it will look like duplicate and its just a quality difference.

If you have any better solution to this problem please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Having two videos titled `something` and `something [HD version]` would probably cause the least confusion while also preserving the statistics on the original video.